# Clear current object or create new one in python

Tags: python

I have written a class in Python for a burning forest model. During the calculation of clusters I receive a Memory error. So I started to optimize my program. My question is - if we have an object with some attributes, do stuff on that object and change values of that object, is it better to clear current object and redo stuff on new attribute values, or should I just create a new object (overwriting the old one)?

This uses a class like this:

```
class BurningForrest:
    def __init__(self, L, p):
        self.L = L
        self.p = p
        self.burning_list = []

    def dostuff(self):
        self.L += 5
        self.burning_list.append(self.L)

    def clear_all(self, L):
        self.L = L
        self.burning_list = []
```

So is it better to do:

```
# [A]
x = BurningForest(5, 0.2)
x.dostuff()
x = BurningForest(5, 0.2)
x.dostuff() # new iteration
```

or:

```
# [B]
x = BurningForest(5, 0.2)
x.dostuff()
x = clear_all(8)
x.dostuff() # new iteration
```

I'm making a lot of Monte Carlo repetitions and right now in every iteration I'm overwriting current object (type `[A]` ). Does it make a difference? Does creating new object is somehow more energy consuming than changing 80% of its attributes?

Comment: I doubt it makes much difference, energy or memory consumption-wise consumption-wise.

Comment: if you want clear values which you normally set `__init__` then move them to other function - ie `reset()` and then you can run it in `__init__` to set values at start, and later you can run directly `x.reset()` to clear it. This method is sometimes used in games - when user loose all lives then it runs `.reset()` to start new game.

Comment: What is the actual memory error you're getting? It is unlikely your class recreation or reuse strategy is really contributing to your difficulties - and if it is the solution is unlikely to be a tradeoff between recreation or reuse, and instead between a class or some other data structure.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is difference in time but i think if it has less values to set again then it may use less time and it may reuse memory. And it can be more readable when you clear/reset values. It shows that still some values are the same.

You could even use `clear_all()` in `__init__`

```
class BurningForrest:
    
    def __init__(self, L, p):
        self.p = p
        self.clear_all(L)  # <---
        
    def clear_all(self, L):
        self.L = L
        self.burning_list = []
```

Or I would use `clear_all` directly in interation

```
class BurningForrest:
    
    def __init__(self, p):
        self.p = p
        # without clear_all
        
    def clear_all(self, L):
        self.L = L
        self.burning_list = []        

# ---

x = BurningForrest(5)

# iteration 1

x.clear_all(0.2)
x.dostuff()

# iteration 2

x.clear_all(8)
x.dostuff()
```